# output didn't came out in if statement matlab

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I would like to get an output for angle2 in my worksheet. However, angle2 remains as zeros. what went wrong? Output didn't get generated in the 'if statement' below.

```
angle = atan2(r - cy, c - cx); %Calculate the angle from centroid cx,cy
angle1 = angle * 360 / (2*pi); %Convert my angle in degree
angle2 = zeros(size(angle1)); %Set angle2 as zeros value with size 320X1 
    if (angle1 < 0) 
    angle2 = angle1 + 360; %Adding any negative angle values to 360 so i get the values from 1-360 degree
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `angle1` a vector? if statements are not vectorized, so you will not enter the if statement unless all angles are smaller than 0. A vectorized appoach is,

```
angle = atan2(r - cy, c - cx); %Calculate the angle from centroid cx,cy
angle1 = angle * 360 / (2*pi); %Convert my angle in degree
angle2 = min(angle1,0);
angle2(angle2<0) = angle2(angle2<0)+360;
% angle2 = mod(angle2,360); % or use modolus, see later section.
```

However, if the problem is not that, but that you want to convert all the negative angles to positive in vector `angle1` it is possible as well.

```
angle = atan2(r - cy, c - cx); %Calculate the angle from centroid cx,cy
angle1 = angle * 360 / (2*pi); %Convert my angle in degree
angle1(angle1<0) = angle1(angle1<0) + 360;
```

That would save you the need to replace the values in `angle1` with values from `angle2`. An operation that is not posted, but as I guess would have to be somewhere in your code if this is what you are after.

You can also use modolus for the second example to get an equivalent output. I am not sure if this operation is better in anyway, but it is at least possible (and in my opinion quite beautiful).

```
angle = atan2(r - cy, c - cx); %Calculate the angle from centroid cx,cy
angle1 = angle * 360 / (2*pi); %Convert my angle in degree
angle1 = mod(angle1,360);
```

Comment: your second and third example works really fine. never heard of mod before, now i learn something new. thanks!

Comment: @syakey modolus is the what is over in a division. For example, 13/7 is 1+6/7, the modulus is then 6: 25/6 is 4+1/6, modolus is then 1.

Answer (score 0):

Well your angle2 remains zero in case angle1 was not negative. Check [this matlab page](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html#moreabout) to see the dependency between atan2 and quaternions. Now if you wish to use angle2 regardless of angle1, you need to modify your code to either make angle1 positive or just take over the value:

```
angle = atan2(r - cy, c - cx);   % Calculate the angle from centroid cx,cy
angle1 = angle * 360 / (2*pi);   % Convert my angle in degree
angle2 = zeros(size(angle1));    % Set angle2 as zeros value with size 320X1 

if (angle1 < 0) 
    angle2 = angle1 + 360; %Adding any negative angle values to 360 so i get the values from 1-360 degree
else
    angle2 = angle1;  % I think this is what you want
end
```

Comment: I think that OP works with coordinates. Try `atan2(-1,1)` which does indeed give `-pi/2` as expected.

Comment: Well then I misunderstood your question to be honest.